# Example Case or IF Statement in SQL

Tags: sql, case

I have a query as follows:

```
 SELECT A.BELEGNR, A.BEZEICH, A.PREIS, A.BUDATUM, A.P_RG_BEZAH, B.BEDINGUNG, A.LIEFERANT,
 A.NAME, A.KENN_FREI, A.KURS, A.VALUTA_DAT
 FROM   A
 LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON B.BED_NR=A.ZBD AND A.SPRACHE=B.SPRACHE
 WHERE
 A.P_RG_BEZAH=0  AND A.KENN_FREI<>'E'
 AND
 if A.GESCH_BER IN (002,005) and A.LIEFERANT not in ('600099','601922')
 else A.LIEFERANT not in ('600299','601519') and A.VALUTA_DAT > getdate()
```

I would like to use Case or IF Statement for the last part:

```
if A.GESCH_BER IN (002,005) and A.LIEFERANT not in ('600099','601922')
else A.LIEFERANT not in ('600299','601519') and A.VALUTA_DAT > getdate()
```

Tried many options, and not knowing further.

Thank you.

Comment: It's generally better to use regular AND/OR constructions in the WHERE clause.

Comment: what would your `then` be like in your if-else?

Comment: actually there would be no then. I am not sure right now.

Answer (score 1):

you should use AND/OR like this:

```
 WHERE A.P_RG_BEZAH=0  
   AND A.KENN_FREI<>'E'
   AND ((A.GESCH_BER IN (002,005) and A.LIEFERANT not in ('600099','601922')) OR 
        (A.LIEFERANT not in ('600299','601519') and A.VALUTA_DAT > getdate()))
```

Comment: This works well. I had a similiar solution already, but this is better structured. Thank you.